# Text is fading out immediately rather than over time

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to fade text out using pure Javascript during an animation.  However, rather than doing this, my script is fading it out immediately.  Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to fix it without using jQuery?
**HTML**

```
<div id="scrollingTextHolder">
    <p id="scrollingText">Hello</p>
    <button id="moveText">Move Text</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#scrollingText{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 25px;
    color: black;
}
```

**JS**

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    var scrollSpeed = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(callback){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60)
        };

    var moveText = document.getElementById("moveText");
    function animateText(){
        var scrollingTextElement = document.getElementById("scrollingText");
        var currentPosition = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(scrollingTextElement).getPropertyValue("margin-top"));
        var moveTo = 247;
        scrollingTextElement.style.opacity = scrollingTextElement.style.opacity - 0.1;
        console.log(scrollingTextElement.style.opacity);
        if(currentPosition <= moveTo){
            scrollingTextElement.style.marginTop = (currentPosition + 3) +"px";
        }

        if(currentPosition == moveTo){
            cancelAnimationFrame(requestAnimationFrame(animateText));
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(animateText);
    }
    moveText.addEventListener("click", function(){
        requestAnimationFrame(animateText);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An element's `style` property returns an empty string *unless* the style was set previously with JavaScript or it was set inline.

Therefore, the first time this line is called:

```
scrollingTextElement.style.opacity = scrollingTextElement.style.opacity - 0.1;
```

... it's the same as doing this:

```
scrollingTextElement.style.opacity = '' - 0.1;
```

Due to how JavaScript handles type conversion, `'' - 0.1` becomes `-0.1`, which makes the element disappear immediately.

To resolve this, you can use **[Window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)** to get the true value of the element's opacity like this:

```
scrollingTextElement.style.opacity = 
  getComputedStyle(scrollingTextElement).getPropertyValue('opacity') - 0.1;
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/c6ju7ogn/)